# Nginx + php-fpm always returns http 500

Tags: nginx, php

I am having a problem with my nginx (and php-fpm) virtual host configuration. The problem is all requests (except static files) return HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is my nginx vh code

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/somesite/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name somesite.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

However when I serve using php's inbuilt development server everything works fine. FYI it's a laravel app

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check that your Laravel directories have the correct write permissions so php-fpm can access them?

Comment: just did, everything is ok... still not working though

Comment: Is Laravel giving you an error with a traceback? I've had 500 errors with with no error indication from Laravel -- turns out the "storage" directory has to be writable by both the Laravel user and php-fpm (and they are not necessarily the same).

Comment: I get no error indication, lemme double check that... Thx for the response

Comment: not having much luck, turns out the storage directory is writable by both php-fpm and laravel (same user in my case)

Comment: If Laravel is getting a request or error, it will log it in a log file inside "storage/logs" -- in my case Laravel was not able to write anything in the log so it wasn't reporting an error at all. That was the source of the mysterious 500 errors in my setup. My php-fpm runs as `www-data` so that's what I ended up setting the owner to for all directories and logs inside "storage."

Comment: Whoah, that worked. set ownership to www-data without even thinking about it... Thanks mate

Comment: No problem. This is a known quirk of Laravel (and other php frameworks) -- because it uses php-fpm which usually requires a different set of permissions that the website virtual host user.